# Postgres JSON Query anonymous rray

Tags: json, postgresql

How can I query the following JSON in postgresql?
Each row would have a similar layout.

Column name: `actions`
`[{"A": 10, "action": "fly"}, {"B": 2, "action": "swim"}]`

I want to get the sum of all values with key `A`.

I can get the data back with:

`select actions from t`

But the following gets error `ERROR: column "actions" does not exists`

`select actions #> 'A' from t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array elements and pick only those that have a key `A`:

```
select sum( (t.o ->> 'A')::int )
from the_table d
  join lateral jsonb_array_elements(d.actions) as t(o) on o ? 'A'
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MYGMI38108

Comment: nice usage of `?`

Comment: Getting an error `HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` Not sure if because `actions` is of type `JSON` and not `JSONB`. I did switch to `json_array_elements` but still didn't work.

Comment: Not sure if the version matters 11.2

Comment: Got it to work by casting d.action to `d.actions::jsonb`

Comment: @drum it seems your `actions` column is a `json` rather than a `jsonb`. It is more efficient to use `jsonb`, so you might want to change the data type for that column permanently.